# how to read cookie to maintain user session in react?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am trying to implement a user login with react. I'm sending a cookie created with cookie-parser from node to maintain the user session, but I can't access that value with react, I tried with the js-cookie library but it doesn't read the value of a cookie already created, it always returns an empty object.
Any idea or suggestion? Thanks.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7GJs.png)

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import './style.scss'
import {Link, Redirect} from 'react-router-dom'
import axios from 'axios';
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';

export default function Login(props) {
const [data, setData] = useState({})
const [error,setError] = useState('')
const [login, setLogin] = useState(false)


const endpoint = "http://localhost:4000/users/login"

 axios.defaults.withCredentials = true

function handleChange(e) {
    const {name,value} = e.target;
    setData({

        ...data,
        [name] : value
    })

}

useEffect(() =>  {
  axios.get(endpoint).then(res => {
      console.log(res.data)
      
  }) }, [login])


const read = Cookies.get()
console.log(read)

const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    axios.post(endpoint,data).then(res => {
      
            console.log(res)
            setLogin(true)
          
            }).catch(Error => {
            setError("error")
    })
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that when you read that cookie it is already declared? Maybe there is a time interval, did you try to make setInterval and see if you will get it after some seconds?

Comment: where are you saving the cookie ?

Comment: the cookie comes from the backend when performing the post method with handlesubmit, it verifies that the user is registered and returns the user's data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to set cookie in order to do authentication , after a user login , you need to send a token from backend , and later you need to save it , set a expiry date for it and later read it and send it every time you make a post or put request from the cookie to validate user , if cookie is invalid then logout the user , you can use these js functions to set, delete , get , update cookies

```
 function setCookie(cookieName, cookieValue, expiryHour) {
  let d = new Date();
  d.setTime(d.getTime() + expiryHour * 60 * 60 * 1000);
  let expires = 'expires=' + d.toUTCString();
  document.cookie = cookieName + '=' + cookieValue + ';' + expires + ';path=/';
}



 function getCookie(cookieName) {
  let name = cookieName + '=';
  let ca = document.cookie.split(';');
  for (let i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
    let c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) === ' ') {
      c = c.substring(1);
    }
    if (c.indexOf(name) === 0) {
      return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
  }
  return '';
}


 function checkCookie(cookieName) {
  let cookie = getCookie(cookieName);
  if (cookie !== '') {
    console.log(cookie + 'exist');
  } else {
    console.log('cookie doesnot exist set the cookie again');
  }
}


 function removeCookie(cookieName, path = '/') {
  document.cookie =
    cookieName + `=; Path=${path}; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT`;
}
```